Google Maps Api road bug on mobile
i am having some trouble for some time with my PWA made in react and google maps, i am using vis.gl/react-google-maps, the problem is that the roads are not displayed on mobile, map works fine on chrome desktop but as an installed app on android it has some bugs, meaning it sometimes work sometimes it doesnt. i opened the site on Edge and it worked a bit until i refreshed or reopened the tab, same with firefox. I am using chrome for some time so i had this problem almost permanently. im thinking it could be some cache issues.
Here are some images but the theme doesnt matter
Roads are not displayed

Correct way to display roads

i tried clearing the cache, reinstalling the app, prevent caching from google maps url

Just to be clear, you're using @react-google-maps/api?

no, @vis.gl/react-google-maps

You said this is only happening on an installed android app? Do you happen to be using an app packager like React Native/Expo? If so, it's possible the google maps api has incompatible dependencies. It may also rely on browser features that aren't present in the app environment.

the PWA app can be installed as a browser app, even the google play version which i used bubblewrap cli to convert to apk, havent used expo manager.

If you visit the packages npm page, you'll see a banner at the top saying the package is in "alpha phase". They recommend updating to the latest version (published 3 days ago). If that doesn't work, you should consider opening a new issue on their github page or ask this question in their discussion section.
Alternatively, using a more stable package like @react-google-maps/api may be a better choice for your project.
